# wordpress function to change post status

Tags: plugins, post-status, wp-update-post

I'm running the [YouTube Video Fetcher](http://wordpress.org/plugins/youtube-video-fetcher/) plugin at . It fetches videos using the youtube api and displays them on your website.

Within the plugin script, there is the following sequence:

```
    if (empty($items)) {$ret .= " 'No new videos.'";}
    else foreach ( $items as $item ) :
```

Is it possible to change the wordpress post status from published to draft if "No new videos" are found?

I am thinking the solution is using the wp update post function and something along the lines of the following:

```
        <?php
        // Update post
        $my_post = array();
        $my_post['ID'] = $id;
        $my_post['post_status'] = 'draft';

        // Update the post into the database
        wp_update_post( $my_post );
        ?>
```

Comment: As long as your `$id` is set and valid this should work. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I guess it should work . As long as `$id` is available things are easy.

```
<?php
if (empty($items)) {
$ret .= " 'No new videos.'";
$postid = $post->ID; //Supply post-Id here $post->ID.
    wp_update_post(array(
        'ID'    =>  $postid,
        'post_status'   =>  'draft'
        ));
}
else
    foreach ( $items as $item ) :
?>
```

Give it a shot.